# Time series prediction code fails to run in an iterative loop, but works when run out of loop

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series

I have a dataset with four columns and 2200 rows of data as shown below :

```
            Datetime    Simulated Pump Pressure Prediction  Cumulative Temp Exposure Prediction Zero Frequency Prediction
0   2017-08-29 17:03:25            0.951528                           1892.204956              14.0
1   2017-08-29 17:03:30            0.946481                           1892.392944              14.0
```

I perform a time series forecast using a sliding window technique, by using past 2000 time steps and predicting the next 100 time steps. At the end I append the predictions to the dataset above and in next prediction I use the latest 2000 time steps to predict next 100. Here is the code that does this succesfully

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
from tsai.inference import load_learner

# Load the model
learn = load_learner('models/patchTST.pt')

# Load the dataset
final_df = pd.read_csv('58_32_predictions.csv')

# Preprocess the data
fcst_history = 2000  # as you mentioned needing the last 2000 timesteps
dates = final_df["Datetime"].tail(fcst_history)
new_df = final_df[final_df["Datetime"].isin(dates)].reset_index(drop=True)
#new_df = learn.transform(new_df)

# Prepare the data for prediction
x_vars = ['Simulated Pump Pressure Prediction', 'Cumulative Temp Exposure Prediction', 'Zero Frequency Prediction']
new_X, _ = prepare_forecasting_data(new_df, fcst_history=fcst_history, fcst_horizon=0, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=None)

# Generate predictions using the model
new_scaled_preds, *_ = learn.get_X_preds(new_X)
new_scaled_preds = to_np(new_scaled_preds).squeeze(0)

# Add the generated predictions to the dataframe
dates = pd.date_range(start=final_df["Datetime"].iloc[-1], periods=101, freq='1H')[1:]
preds_df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=["Datetime"])
preds_df[x_vars] = new_scaled_preds.T

# Append predictions to the dataset and save
final_df = pd.concat([final_df, preds_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
final_df.to_csv('58_32_predictions.csv', index=False)
```

But here is when the problem occurs. I try to perform an iterative loop of predictions until a threshold is reached in one of the columns called "Cumulative Temp Exposure".

```
from tsai.inference import load_learner
import pandas as pd

# Load the trained learner
learn = load_learner('models/patchTST.pt')

# Threshold for "Cumulative Temp Exposure Prediction"
threshold = 14000  # replace with your defined value

while final_df["Cumulative Temp Exposure Prediction"].iloc[-1] < threshold:
    
    # Use the last 2000 timesteps for prediction
    data_to_predict = final_df.iloc[-2000:].drop("Datetime", axis=1).values[None]
    
    # Convert data to tensor
    X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(data_to_predict)

    # Generate predictions using the model
    y_pred_tensor, *_ = learn.get_X_preds(X_tensor)
    y_pred = to_np(y_pred_tensor).squeeze(0)

    # Create a new dataframe to store the predictions
    predictions_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Datetime": pd.date_range(start=final_df["Datetime"].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5), periods=100, freq='5T'),
        "Simulated Pump Pressure Prediction": y_pred[:, 0],
        "Cumulative Temp Exposure Prediction": y_pred[:, 1],
        "Zero Frequency Prediction": y_pred[:, 2]
    })

    # Append the predictions to the original dataframe
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, predictions_df], ignore_index=True)

# Save updated dataframe to CSV
final_df.to_csv("58_32_predictions.csv", index=False)

# Print the total number of rows in the updated CSV file
print(f"Total rows in 58_32_predictions.csv after reaching the threshold: {len(final_df)}")
```

However, when I run the code it throws error regarding the input size of data.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[121], line 19
     16 X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(data_to_predict)
     18 # Generate predictions using the model
---> 19 y_pred_tensor, *_ = learn.get_X_preds(X_tensor)
     20 y_pred = to_np(y_pred_tensor).squeeze(0)
     22 # Create a new dataframe to store the predictions

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsai/inference.py:25, in get_X_preds(self, X, y, bs, with_input, with_decoded, with_loss, act)
     23     with_loss = False
     24 dl = self.dls.valid.new_dl(X, y=y, bs=bs)
---> 25 output = list(self.get_preds(dl=dl, with_input=with_input, with_decoded=with_decoded, with_loss=with_loss, reorder=False, act=act))
     26 if with_decoded and len(self.dls.tls) >= 2 and hasattr(self.dls.tls[-1], "tfms") and hasattr(self.dls.tls[-1].tfms, "decodes"):
     27     output[2 + with_input] = self.dls.tls[-1].tfms.decode(output[2 + with_input])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:308, in Learner.get_preds(self, ds_idx, dl, with_input, with_decoded, with_loss, act, inner, reorder, cbs, **kwargs)
    306 if with_loss: ctx_mgrs.append(self.loss_not_reduced())
    307 with ContextManagers(ctx_mgrs):
--> 308     self._do_epoch_validate(dl=dl)
    309     if act is None: act = getcallable(self.loss_func, 'activation')
    310     res = cb.all_tensors()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:244, in Learner._do_epoch_validate(self, ds_idx, dl)
    242 if dl is None: dl = self.dls[ds_idx]
    243 self.dl = dl
--> 244 with torch.no_grad(): self._with_events(self.all_batches, 'validate', CancelValidException)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:205, in Learner.all_batches(self)
    203 def all_batches(self):
    204     self.n_iter = len(self.dl)
--> 205     for o in enumerate(self.dl): self.one_batch(*o)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsai/learner.py:40, in one_batch(self, i, b)
     38 b_on_device = to_device(b, device=self.dls.device) if self.dls.device is not None else b
     39 self._split(b_on_device)
---> 40 self._with_events(self._do_one_batch, 'batch', CancelBatchException)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:199, in Learner._with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final)
    198 def _with_events(self, f, event_type, ex, final=noop):
--> 199     try: self(f'before_{event_type}');  f()
    200     except ex: self(f'after_cancel_{event_type}')
    201     self(f'after_{event_type}');  final()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py:216, in Learner._do_one_batch(self)
    215 def _do_one_batch(self):
--> 216     self.pred = self.model(*self.xb)
    217     self('after_pred')
    218     if len(self.yb):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsai/models/PatchTST.py:464, in PatchTST.forward(self, x)
    462     x = res + trend
    463 else:
--> 464     x = self.model(x)
    465 return x

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tsai/models/PatchTST.py:382, in _PatchTST_backbone.forward(self, z)
    380 b, c, s = z.size()
    381 z = z.reshape(-1, 1, 1, s)
--> 382 z = self.unfold(z)
    383 z = z.permute(0, 2, 1).reshape(b, c, -1, self.patch_len).permute(0, 1, 3, 2)
    385 # model

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/fold.py:298, in Unfold.forward(self, input)
    297 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 298     return F.unfold(input, self.kernel_size, self.dilation,
    299                     self.padding, self.stride)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:4697, in unfold(input, kernel_size, dilation, padding, stride)
   4693 if has_torch_function_unary(input):
   4694     return handle_torch_function(
   4695         unfold, (input,), input, kernel_size, dilation=dilation, padding=padding, stride=stride
   4696     )
-> 4697 return torch._C._nn.im2col(input, _pair(kernel_size), _pair(dilation), _pair(padding), _pair(stride))

RuntimeError: Given input with spatial size (1, 1), kernel_size=(1, 24), dilation=(1, 1), padding=(0, 0), calculated shape of the array of sliding blocks as (1, -9), but its components must be at least one.
```

What have I tried so far? Well I have tried every option that Chat GPT and Bard AI threw at me such as padding the data with zeroes to match the shape etc. But the error persists.

In short the prediction is successful if performed in a single iteration. For multiple iteration the time series prediction throws an error